# Do I have stuck queries?

Tags: postgresql

I'm running the following query:

```
select *
from pg_stat_activity
```

and getting:

```
dataid   dataname   username   waitevent        query
16384      my_db       pos12     clientRead     query_1
16384      my_db       pos12     clientRead     query_2
16384      my_db       pos12     clientRead     query_3
```

where query_1, query_2, query_3 are some select queries

There are no applications which running and querying the database.

- Does it mean that those queries are old stuck queries?
- How can I know if there are old stuck queries?
- Do stuck queries occupied DB resources?

Comment: [This gist](https://gist.github.com/rgreenjr/3637525) has helped me a lot in the past

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions that are in state `ClientRead` are idle, waiting for the next command from the client.

Whether that is a problem from the database side or not depends on the `state`:

- if the `state` is `idle`, the session is not consuming any resources (save for some little memory) and is quite harmless
- if the `state` is `idle in transaction` for a longer time, the sessions hold locks and block database maintenance – this would be an application bug that has to be fixed there

At any rate, if these are all your sessions, then the database is idle, and if anything is stuck, it is in the client side.